# Custom Authentication Provider for ASP.NET and MVC3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I am looking for information on how to build out a custom authentication provider. I have to interface with a rather odd authentication/authorization scheme and it would be nice if it just “plugged” into asp.net.  Any links would be helpful.

I figured out how to write a custom Authorize attribute, but how to get the authentication part in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ASP.NET authentication is typically implemented as a [MembershipProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.aspx) while authorization is typically implemented as a [RoleProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roleprovider.aspx). Both can then be augmented by a [ProfileProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.profile.profileprovider.aspx) if you need to display extra information from a user's account.

- [Introduction to Membership](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.aspx)
- [Managing Authorization Using Roles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9ab2fxh0.aspx)
- [ASP.NET Profile Properties Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2y3fs9xs.aspx)

Each of your custom providers (you may only need the first, but it depends on your needs) can then be configured in web.config.

Answer (score 3):

When it comes to MVC, you can install the NuGet package **FluentSecurity** and decorate all controller actions with the `HandleSecurityAttribute`. Afterwards, you only have to configure an appropriate `Func<bool>` in FluentSecurity's `GetAuthenticationStatusFrom` method. For more information, please refer to my blog post [Securing an ASP.NET MVC Application using FluentSecurity](http://www.marius-schulz.net/blog/securing-an-aspnet-mvc-application-using-fluentsecurity).